# Use modal transitions/animations for push segue in Xcode Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

The modal segues have cool animations for transitions (e.g., Partial Curl, Flip Horizontal). While we understand why Apple may believe these transitions/animations do not naturally fit for push segues and the navigation controller model, it would still be interesting to have *the option* to apply some of these animations to push segues from Storyboard.

Is this possible, or is the only option to write custom segues that mimic these animations?

We're using Swift 2.

Comment: Nowadays, rather than custom segues, you'd do custom transitions as described in WWDC 2013 [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-218/) (e.g. specify delegate for nav controller, implement `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:` and then write `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` objects that implement `animateTransition`). But, yes, for custom navigation controller transitions, you'd write the animation code yourself.